# Get the value of a select field from a ".row" in the click event using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, events, jquery-events

I have a user document record where I add or remove rows dynamically and control their indexes.

[image]

Each row is inside the div called "div-documentos". I created two events: the "click" event (to store the value of select "sel-document-tipo" of each row) and the "change" event to perform an action after the user selects an option in select.
The problem is that the click event is unable to get the value of the field select from the respective row, that is, it is bringing the value from another row different from the current row.

```
var documentoTipoIdPrevious = "0";
$("#div-documentos").bind("click", ".sel-documento-tipo", function (e) {
    //get current row select value
    //is not working
    documentoTipoIdPrevious = $(this).closest('.row').find('.sel-documento-tipo').val();
    alert(documentoTipoIdPrevious)

}).on("change", ".sel-documento-tipo", function (e) {
//it's working  
});
```

What is wrong? Why are you taking the select value from another different row?

HTML:

```
    <div class="col-md-12" id="div-documentos" data-select2-id="div-documentos">

    <div class="form-group align-items-center row" data-select2-id="34">
        <div class="card card-shadow col-md-12 pl-0 pr-o pt-0 pb-0 border border-default" data-select2-id="33">
            <div class="card-block">
                        <h4 class="card-title"><i class="icon fa-address-book-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>TÍTULO DE ELEITOR</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="card-block" data-select2-id="32">
                <div class="form-group align-items-center">
                    <input class="hid-id" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Id field is required." id="PessoaViewModel_PessoasDocumentosViewModel_0__Id" name="PessoaViewModel.PessoasDocumentosViewModel[0].Id" type="hidden" value="13">
                    <input class="hid-pessoaId" data-val="true" data-val-required="Escolha uma Pessoa" id="PessoaViewModel_PessoasDocumentosViewModel_0__PessoaId" name="PessoaViewModel.PessoasDocumentosViewModel[0].PessoaId" type="hidden" value="4">
                    <input class="hid-documento-tipo-descricao" id="PessoaViewModel_PessoasDocumentosViewModel_0__DocumentoTipoDescricao" name="PessoaViewModel.PessoasDocumentosViewModel[0].DocumentoTipoDescricao" type="hidden" value="TÍTULO DE ELEITOR">

                    <div class="col-md-6" data-select2-id="31">
                        <label class="control-label lb-documento-tipo" for="PessoaViewModel_PessoasDocumentosViewModel_0__DocumentoTipoId">Tipo de Documento</label>
                        <select data-id="7" title="Selecione uma opção" class="form-control sel-documento-tipo select2-hidden-accessible" data-val="true" data-val-required="Escolha um Tipo de Documento" id="PessoaViewModel_PessoasDocumentosViewModel_0__DocumentoTipoId" name="PessoaViewModel.PessoasDocumentosViewModel[0].DocumentoTipoId" data-select2-id="PessoaViewModel_PessoasDocumentosViewModel_0__DocumentoTipoId" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true"><option value="" data-select2-id="45"></option><option value="1" data-select2-id="46">CPF - CADASTRO NACIONAL DE PESSOA FÍSICA</option>
                            <option value="3" data-select2-id="47">RG - REGISTRO GERAL</option>
                            <option value="4" data-select2-id="48">RNE - REGISTRO NACIONAL DE ESTRANGEIROS</option>
                            <option selected="selected" value="7" data-select2-id="14">TÍTULO DE ELEITOR</option>
                            <option value="8" data-select2-id="49">CTPS - CARTEIRA DE TRABALHO E PREVIDÊNCIA SOCIAL</option>
                            <option value="9" data-select2-id="50">CNH - CARTEIRA NACIONAL DE HABILITAÇÃO</option>
                            <option value="10" data-select2-id="51">CAM - CERTIFICADO DE ALISTAMENTO MILITAR</option>
                            <option value="11" data-select2-id="52">PASSAPORTE</option>
                            <option value="12" data-select2-id="53">NIS - NÚMERO DE IDENTIFICAÇÃO SOCIAL</option>
                            </select><span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--default select2-container--below" dir="ltr" data-select2-id="13" style="width: auto;"><span class="selection"><span class="select2-selection select2-selection--single" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" title="Selecione uma opção" tabindex="0" aria-labelledby="select2-PessoaViewModel_PessoasDocumentosViewModel_0__DocumentoTipoId-container"><span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-PessoaViewModel_PessoasDocumentosViewModel_0__DocumentoTipoId-container" role="textbox" aria-readonly="true" title="CPF - CADASTRO NACIONAL DE PESSOA FÍSICA"><span class="select2-selection__clear" data-select2-id="54">×</span>CPF - CADASTRO NACIONAL DE PESSOA FÍSICA</span><span class="select2-selection__arrow" role="presentation"><b role="presentation"></b></span></span></span><span class="dropdown-wrapper" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>
                        <span class="text-danger val-documento-tipo field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="PessoaViewModel.PessoasDocumentosViewModel[0].DocumentoTipoId" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label class="control-label lb-documento" for="PessoaViewModel_PessoasDocumentosViewModel_0__Documento">Núm. Documento</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control txt-documento" data-val="true" data-val-maxlength="O campo Documento deve ter no máximo 30 caracteres" data-val-maxlength-max="30" data-val-required="O campo Número do Documento é obrigatório" id="PessoaViewModel_PessoasDocumentosViewModel_0__Documento" name="PessoaViewModel.PessoasDocumentosViewModel[0].Documento" value="12345">
                        <span class="text-danger val-documento field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="PessoaViewModel.PessoasDocumentosViewModel[0].Documento" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-block">
                <div class="card-actions float-right">
                    <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-icon btn-default btn-outline btn-remover-documento" title="Excluir Documento"><i class="icon wb-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group align-items-center row" data-select2-id="59">
        <div class="card card-shadow col-md-12 pl-0 pr-o pt-0 pb-0 border border-default" data-select2-id="58">
            <div class="card-block">
                        <h4 class="card-title"><i class="icon wb-payment" aria-hidden="true"></i>CPF - CADASTRO NACIONAL DE PESSOA FÍSICA</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="card-block" data-select2-id="57">
                <div class="form-group align-items-center">
                    <input class="hid-id" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Id field is required." id="PessoaViewModel_PessoasDocumentosViewModel_1__Id" name="PessoaViewModel.PessoasDocumentosViewModel[1].Id" type="hidden" value="14">
                    <input class="hid-pessoaId" data-val="true" data-val-required="Escolha uma Pessoa" id="PessoaViewModel_PessoasDocumentosViewModel_1__PessoaId" name="PessoaViewModel.PessoasDocumentosViewModel[1].PessoaId" type="hidden" value="4">
                    <input class="hid-documento-tipo-descricao" id="PessoaViewModel_PessoasDocumentosViewModel_1__DocumentoTipoDescricao" name="PessoaViewModel.PessoasDocumentosViewModel[1].DocumentoTipoDescricao" type="hidden" value="CPF - CADASTRO NACIONAL DE PESSOA FÍSICA">

                    <div class="col-md-6" data-select2-id="56">
                        <label class="control-label lb-documento-tipo" for="PessoaViewModel_PessoasDocumentosViewModel_1__DocumentoTipoId">Tipo de Documento</label>
                        <select data-id="1" title="Selecione uma opção" class="form-control sel-documento-tipo select2-hidden-accessible" data-val="true" data-val-required="Escolha um Tipo de Documento" id="PessoaViewModel_PessoasDocumentosViewModel_1__DocumentoTipoId" name="PessoaViewModel.PessoasDocumentosViewModel[1].DocumentoTipoId" data-select2-id="PessoaViewModel_PessoasDocumentosViewModel_1__DocumentoTipoId" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true"><option value="" data-select2-id="60"></option><option selected="selected" value="1" data-select2-id="17">CPF - CADASTRO NACIONAL DE PESSOA FÍSICA</option>
                        <option value="3" data-select2-id="61">RG - REGISTRO GERAL</option>
                        <option value="4" data-select2-id="62">RNE - REGISTRO NACIONAL DE ESTRANGEIROS</option>
                        <option value="7" data-select2-id="63">TÍTULO DE ELEITOR</option>
                        <option value="8" data-select2-id="64">CTPS - CARTEIRA DE TRABALHO E PREVIDÊNCIA SOCIAL</option>
                        <option value="9" data-select2-id="65">CNH - CARTEIRA NACIONAL DE HABILITAÇÃO</option>
                        <option value="10" data-select2-id="66">CAM - CERTIFICADO DE ALISTAMENTO MILITAR</option>
                        <option value="11" data-select2-id="67">PASSAPORTE</option>
                        <option value="12" data-select2-id="68">NIS - NÚMERO DE IDENTIFICAÇÃO SOCIAL</option>
                        </select><span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--default select2-container--above" dir="ltr" data-select2-id="16" style="width: auto;"><span class="selection"><span class="select2-selection select2-selection--single" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" title="Selecione uma opção" tabindex="0" aria-labelledby="select2-PessoaViewModel_PessoasDocumentosViewModel_1__DocumentoTipoId-container"><span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-PessoaViewModel_PessoasDocumentosViewModel_1__DocumentoTipoId-container" role="textbox" aria-readonly="true" title="CPF - CADASTRO NACIONAL DE PESSOA FÍSICA"><span class="select2-selection__clear" data-select2-id="18">×</span>CPF - CADASTRO NACIONAL DE PESSOA FÍSICA</span><span class="select2-selection__arrow" role="presentation"><b role="presentation"></b></span></span></span><span class="dropdown-wrapper" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>
                        <span class="text-danger val-documento-tipo field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="PessoaViewModel.PessoasDocumentosViewModel[1].DocumentoTipoId" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label class="control-label lb-documento" for="PessoaViewModel_PessoasDocumentosViewModel_1__Documento">Núm. Documento</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control txt-documento" data-val="true" data-val-maxlength="O campo Documento deve ter no máximo 30 caracteres" data-val-maxlength-max="30" data-val-required="O campo Número do Documento é obrigatório" id="PessoaViewModel_PessoasDocumentosViewModel_1__Documento" name="PessoaViewModel.PessoasDocumentosViewModel[1].Documento" value="091.479.907-08" maxlength="14">
                        <span class="text-danger val-documento field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="PessoaViewModel.PessoasDocumentosViewModel[1].Documento" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                    </div>


                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-block">
                <div class="card-actions float-right">
                    <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-icon btn-default btn-outline btn-remover-documento" title="Excluir Documento"><i class="icon wb-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why .bind and .on? .bind is replaced by .on and is deprecated

Comment: This is not related to ASP. f you instead click edit, then `[<>]` snippet editor and post JS and HTML only, then we can test your [mcve]

Comment: Why don't you use just `$(this).val()` instead of `$(this).closest('.row').find('.sel-documento-tipo').val()`

Answer (score 0):

Your code would have been easier to check with pure HTML

I believe I found your issue.

- You want mousedown and change on the select itself.
- No need to navigate to the .row to find the select you are interacting with
- I change to .on in both events

```js
var documentoTipoIdPrevious = "0";
$("#div-documentos").on("mousedown", ".sel-documento-tipo", function(e) {
  documentoTipoIdPrevious = $(this).val();
  console.log("Before", documentoTipoIdPrevious)
}).on("change", ".sel-documento-tipo", function(e) {
  console.log("After", $(this).val())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-12" id="div-documentos" data-select2-id="div-documentos">

  <div class="form-group align-items-center row" data-select2-id="34">
    <div class="card card-shadow col-md-12 pl-0 pr-o pt-0 pb-0 border border-default" data-select2-id="33">
      <div class="card-block">
        <h4 class="card-title"><i class="icon fa-address-book-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>TÍTULO DE ELEITOR</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="card-block" data-select2-id="32">
        <div class="form-group align-items-center">
          <input class="hid-id" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Id field is required." id="PessoaViewModel_PessoasDocumentosViewModel_0__Id" name="PessoaViewModel.PessoasDocumentosViewModel[0].Id" type="hidden" value="13">
          <input class="hid-pessoaId" data-val="true" data-val-required="Escolha uma Pessoa" id="PessoaViewModel_PessoasDocumentosViewModel_0__PessoaId" name="PessoaViewModel.PessoasDocumentosViewModel[0].PessoaId" type="hidden" value="4">
          <input class="hid-documento-tipo-descricao" id="PessoaViewModel_PessoasDocumentosViewModel_0__DocumentoTipoDescricao" name="PessoaViewModel.PessoasDocumentosViewModel[0].DocumentoTipoDescricao" type="hidden" value="TÍTULO DE ELEITOR">

          <div class="col-md-6" data-select2-id="31">
            <label class="control-label lb-documento-tipo" for="PessoaViewModel_PessoasDocumentosViewModel_0__DocumentoTipoId">Tipo de Documento</label>
            <select data-id="7" title="Selecione uma opção" class="form-control sel-documento-tipo select2-hidden-accessible" data-val="true" data-val-required="Escolha um Tipo de Documento" id="PessoaViewModel_PessoasDocumentosViewModel_0__DocumentoTipoId" name="PessoaViewModel.PessoasDocumentosViewModel[0].DocumentoTipoId"
              data-select2-id="PessoaViewModel_PessoasDocumentosViewModel_0__DocumentoTipoId" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
              <option value="" data-select2-id="45"></option>
              <option value="1" data-select2-id="46">CPF - CADASTRO NACIONAL DE PESSOA FÍSICA</option>
              <option value="3" data-select2-id="47">RG - REGISTRO GERAL</option>
              <option value="4" data-select2-id="48">RNE - REGISTRO NACIONAL DE ESTRANGEIROS</option>
              <option selected="selected" value="7" data-select2-id="14">TÍTULO DE ELEITOR</option>
              <option value="8" data-select2-id="49">CTPS - CARTEIRA DE TRABALHO E PREVIDÊNCIA SOCIAL</option>
              <option value="9" data-select2-id="50">CNH - CARTEIRA NACIONAL DE HABILITAÇÃO</option>
              <option value="10" data-select2-id="51">CAM - CERTIFICADO DE ALISTAMENTO MILITAR</option>
              <option value="11" data-select2-id="52">PASSAPORTE</option>
              <option value="12" data-select2-id="53">NIS - NÚMERO DE IDENTIFICAÇÃO SOCIAL</option>
            </select><span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--default select2-container--below" dir="ltr" data-select2-id="13" style="width: auto;"><span class="selection"><span class="select2-selection select2-selection--single" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" title="Selecione uma opção" tabindex="0" aria-labelledby="select2-PessoaViewModel_PessoasDocumentosViewModel_0__DocumentoTipoId-container"><span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-PessoaViewModel_PessoasDocumentosViewModel_0__DocumentoTipoId-container" role="textbox" aria-readonly="true" title="CPF - CADASTRO NACIONAL DE PESSOA FÍSICA"><span class="select2-selection__clear" data-select2-id="54">×</span>CPF
            - CADASTRO NACIONAL DE PESSOA FÍSICA</span><span class="select2-selection__arrow" role="presentation"><b role="presentation"></b></span></span>
            </span><span class="dropdown-wrapper" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>
            <span class="text-danger val-documento-tipo field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="PessoaViewModel.PessoasDocumentosViewModel[0].DocumentoTipoId" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <label class="control-label lb-documento" for="PessoaViewModel_PessoasDocumentosViewModel_0__Documento">Núm. Documento</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control txt-documento" data-val="true" data-val-maxlength="O campo Documento deve ter no máximo 30 caracteres" data-val-maxlength-max="30" data-val-required="O campo Número do Documento é obrigatório" id="PessoaViewModel_PessoasDocumentosViewModel_0__Documento"
              name="PessoaViewModel.PessoasDocumentosViewModel[0].Documento" value="12345">
            <span class="text-danger val-documento field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="PessoaViewModel.PessoasDocumentosViewModel[0].Documento" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Hello @mplungjan! Only the change event is working. I do not know what else to do :(

Comment: @MasterJR I updated with your HTML. My code works as you requested

Answer (score 0):

OK here's what was wrong it was your query

```
$("#div-documentos").bind("click", ".sel-documento-tipo", function (e) {
    //get current row select value
    //is not working
    documentoTipoIdPrevious = $(e.target).val();
    alert(documentoTipoIdPrevious)

}).on("change", ".sel-documento-tipo", function (e) {
//it's working  
});
```

Comment: I updated the post with the generated html. Cannot take value and select if only using "$ (this) .val ();". You can get the value using "$ (this) .closest ('. Row'). Find ('. Sel-documento-tipo'). Val ()", but it's not the value of the current line ... It looks like is getting lost getting the value ...

Comment: There is no need to use e.target when you delegate to the select. Also bind is deprecated. See my answer

Comment: Hello @mplungjan . The mousedown event is not working ... When I change from bind to on the event does not work.

Comment: Would anyone be able to remotely access my pc and check? So we could leave the answer here. I have tried everything ... :(

Comment: did you try using e.target as I mentioned in the update ?